# Is it possible to safely dereference a string

Tags: javascript, memory-management

Let me explain the title.

Say we have a string containing a password, when we have sent this pw e.g to the BE hashed and salted we would like to get rid of the value ever.

So to say, this is not feasible:

```
var pw = 'somePw';
// later
pw = 'someGarbage';
```

Strings are immutable so we won't rewrite the value in memory but creating a new one and the old value is still present in the memory but dereferenced so free'd by GC, still we can get rid of it immediately -> not safe.

How can I overcome this problem?!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Only someone with access to the machine will be able to dump its memory.

Comment: You don't have a problem, you are over-engineering.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to access the raw memory of the Javascript engine.

Comment: Actually I can't do anything about this, external pentesters are checking our  application and this was stated as a possible source of bug. So that in a certain time it can be that a pw is persisted (in memory) and this should not be done. :/

Comment: There are papers on this problem. See "data lifetime is a systems problem".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about how JavaScript internals work, and it is probably implementation-dependent, but perhaps you could store the value as a property of an object and then just delete the property. As deleting the property puts it up for garbage collection, and subsequently free'd, but I don't know if the value would still be in memory somewhere.

```
var passwordObject = { pass: "somepass" };

delete passwordObject.pass;
```

Comment: Thanks, I also thought maybe it would work but I'm uncertain. What does using delete mean?! Does it mean it will erase the memory area or will it label it as "free to be GCd"?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the pw in an object and use the delete operator on it when done.

```
var user = {
   password: "pw"
}

delete user.password
```

You can also set `pw = null`

Both methods will free up the memory space after the garbage collection cycle has taken place.

Douglas crockford prefers the later method and not the first one http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html
as he explains some memory leaks issues associated with the first method. However I don't think these are still an issue in modern browsers.